# Change custom field date formating Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have made a custom field 'Event date' for my custom post type 'Event'. I'm trying to display the date on the front-end and I want to change the format of how the date is displayed, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's what I tried:

```
 <div class="single-post-event-meta">
                <p><?php 

                    $event_date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_event_post_date_value_key');
                    echo $event_date[0]->format('M');
                
                ?></p>
            </div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is `_event_post_date_value_key` an array of serialized `DateTime` objects?

Comment: It gives me a date in yyyy-mm-dd format when I echo it out.  I'm not sure if this answers your question, I'm still quite new to all this

Comment: Try just `var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_event_post_date_value_key'));` to see what's in there, and then edit your question with those results.

Comment: yep just tried that same solution from a different solution I found. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look I answered my own question WoohoooO!

```
<p class="single-post-event-meta-date"><?php 
   echo 'Date: ';
   echo (new DateTime(get_post_meta($post>ID,'_event_post_date_value_key',true)))->format('d M Y');
 ?></p>
```

Comment: Although your code isn't wrong, I strongly recommend, especially in a WordPress context, to add some add additional guards around the code. As it stands, your code calls a WordPress function with a global parameter, passes it to a constructor and invokes a method on the returned object, all in one go, and debugging these kinds of thigs, especially some day in the far future, can be a real pain. This is one way to help improve this: https://3v4l.org/Y7Z5D

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this, I tried to understand your code and implemented it. My question is does this only help with not echoing the custom field when it's left empty or has invalid input, or does this have any other benefits?

Comment: I used your code as a basis to display the Event TIme field, I hope it acts as a similar guard around the code. https://3v4l.org/PQ4GA

Comment: Per the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/), `get_post_meta` might return `false` or an empty string if there's a failure. Your code is assuming that this will never, ever happen, and that might be the case, it might always work. _If_ it doesn't work, maybe another plugin messes with the data or some future change invalidates this logic, your code might result in a white screen or ugly error, while the code I posted should just result in the field not showing on the screen.

Comment: At a quick glance, the provided code also looks good. The only other thing I'd tell you, and my first posted code doesn't have it either, is to get into the habit of always using `esc_html()` and/or `esc_attr()` instead of assuming the data is safe. 99.99% of the time it is overkill, but it is just a best practice to always escape on output. https://3v4l.org/fLrGH

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).